# confusion about evaluation of is_array template class

Tags: c++, object, abstract-class, evaluation, class-template

Consider following program (See live demo [here.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/M0yyRCUZLg0Atb9T))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main()
{
    struct T{ virtual void foo()=0;};
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
    std::cout<<std::is_array<int[3]>::value<<'\n';
    std::cout<<std::is_array<T>::value<<'\n';
    std::cout<<std::is_array<T1[2]>::value<<'\n';
    std::cout<<std::is_array<T[3]>::value<<'\n'; // why uncommenting this line causes compile time error?
}
```

I know that it isn't possible to create the object of abstract class. Here T is abstract, so it isn't possible to create the object of struct T.
But consider the following statement

```
std::cout<<std::is_array<T[3]>::value<<'\n';
```

Why it gives me an error? The statement only checks whether a given type is array or not. Does that mean that If T is array 
& value of the static member `value` evaluates to `true` then array of objects will be created? **But, why array is required to be created here? 
what is the need to create an array If I am not able to use that array? Isn't this just wastage of memory?**

Then why following statement doesn't give any compiler error?

```
std::cout<<std::is_array<T>::value<<'\n';
```

What I am understanding wrong here? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an array of abstract class type. Thus, you get a compiler error.

> But, why array is required to be created here? what is the need to
>   create an array If I am not able to use that array? Isn't this just
>   wastage of memory?

The array is not created, you pass its type as a template argument. The compiler sees that this is an array of abstract class objects and it complains.

Comment: @101010: Then why following std::cout<<std::is_array<T>::value<<'\n'; doesn't give any compiler error?

Comment: @PravasiMeet `std::is_array<T>::value` here `T` is not an array. As cpplearner mentioned the standard forbids arrays of abstract class types.

Comment: @PravasiMeet because `T` is a valid type although you can't create one whereas `T[3]` is not a valid type.

Answer (score 5):

N4567 § 8.3.4 Arrays [dcl.array]p1 (emphasis mine)

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> `D1 [ constant-expression`<sub>`opt`</sub>`] attribute-speciﬁer-seq`<sub>`opt`</sub>
>
> and the type of the identiﬁer in the declaration `T D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”, then the type of the *identiﬁer* of D is an array type; [...] **T is called the *array element type*; this type shall not be a reference type, the (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) type void, a function type or an abstract class type**.

So, the language rule just forbids you from creating the type "array of abstrct class type".